# how can we call a datatable in LogWriter.Write() to create a error log file in Microsoft EnterPriseLibrary 5.0 version

Tags: c#, datatable, enterprise-library

i am using Microsoft EnterPrise Library Version 5.0 to create flat file and as well as send to an email

Here, i created some columns in one datatable and and appending the values to respective columns 
like

```
 DataTable dtErrorLogTable = new Datatable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Success");
    dt.Colums.Add("Failure");
    DataRow dr = dtErrorLogTable.NewRow();
```

and below is my condition to create a log file

```
 try
        {
           File.Copy(Path.Combine(Directory.FullName, file.Name), Path.Combine(destinationFolderFullName, file.Name), true);
dr["Success"] = "true";
dr["Failure"] = "-";
dtErrorLogTable.Rows.Add(dr);
isSuccessful = true;
}

catch(Exception ex)
{

errorMessage = ex.StackTrace;
dr["Success"] = "-";
dr["Failure"] = "true";
dtErrorLogTable.Rows.Add(dr);
isSuccessful = "false";
}
finally
{
StringBuilder sbCopySuccessLog = new StringBuilder();                      
var Container = new UnityContainer();
Container.AddNewExtension<EnterpriseLibraryCoreExtension>();
var log = Container.Resolve<LogWriter>();  
if (isSuccessful)
{
   sbCopySuccessLog.AppendLine("COPY SUCCESS -");
   log.Write(dtErrorLogTable);
}
else
{
sbCopySuccessLog.AppendLine("COPY Failure -");
log.Write(dtErrorLogTable);
}
}
```

in the above code log.write() calling DataTable but it is not showing datatable rows information in trace.log file 
could you please help me, how can we call a datatable in  LogWriter.Write();

Expected Output:- 
Copy Success -
          Success Failure
            true   -         //incase of copy success.
            -      fail      // incase of copy fauilure.`enter code here`